# Wordpress - Pick out specific link and "redirect" it somewhere else

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using this bit of code to generate a menu:

```
          <div id="menu">
  <?php $args = array(
    'depth'        => 1,
    'show_date'    => '',
    'date_format'  => get_option('date_format'),
    'child_of'     => 0,
    'exclude'      => '426, 508',
    'include'      => '',
    'title_li'     => __(''),
    'echo'         => 1,
    'authors'      => '',
    'sort_column'  => 'menu_order, post_title',
    'link_before'  => '',
    'link_after'   => '',
    'walker' => '' ); ?>
    <ul><div class="menu-button"><?php wp_list_pages( $args, 'sort_column=menu_order' ); ?></div></ul>
    </div>
```

It's generating the menu fine but one of the links I need it to goto another page.

Is it possible to pick out that page by ID and tell it to goto a different address? If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using the [Page Links To](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/page-links-to/) plugin to achieve this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the new features of wordpress, it includes a menu system which allows you to create and manage your menus from within the administration panel. You can add existing pages but also links to other websites in the same menu.

read more: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Comment: As far as I can see that still doesn't allow me to single out a specific link to be redirected somewhere else.